# Is it possible to set expiry to redis keys (bulk operation)

Tags: python, redis, redis-cluster, redis-py

I am using mget(keys, *args) to bulk set keys.

I also want to set expiration time to keys. The reason I am using mset is to save calls to redis.

Is there a way to bulk set keys with expiration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no command that sets the TTL for multiple keys, in the fashion that `MSET` works. You can, however, replace the call to `MSET` with a Lua script that does `SETEX` for each key and value passed to it as parameters.